# How can I check if unique values of a column has multiple occurrences for different values of another column in R?

Tags: r, dplyr, data-wrangling

Sample data:

```
set.seed(4)
cl <- sample(LETTERS[1:2], 100, replace = T)
seller <- round(runif(100, min=1, max=80))

df <- data.frame(cl, seller)

    cl seller
1    B     21
2    A     51
3    A     22
4    A     43
5    A     38
6    B     46
7    A     54
8    B     18
9    A     78
.......

99   A     32
100  B      8
```

I want to check the number of times one unique value of `seller` has occurred for both `A` and `B`. Suppose, in the data frame with this particular seed, you'll see 7 has appeared for both A and B, so 7 will be counted.

My attempt:

```
df %>%
  filter(cl=='A')-> d1

df %>%
  filter(cl=='B')-> d2

d3 <- merge(d1, d2, by='seller') %>%
  distinct(seller)

nrow(d3)
17
```

So, 17 sellers have both cl: A and B.

My attempt, so far, has been very sub-optimal. It yields the result, but there has to be a better way with `dplyr` or even with base `R` which I can't figure out. Also, it will be very time-consuming for a bigger data set if I do it like this.

How can I solve this in a better, more tidy way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could use `n_distinct` (assuming only 'A', 'B' values found in 'cl' column):

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    group_by(seller) %>%
    summarise(n = n_distinct(cl), .groups = 'drop') %>%
    filter(n == 2) %>%
    nrow
```

Output:

```
[1] 17
```

---

Or may also do

```
df %>%
    group_by(seller) %>%
    summarise(n = all(c("A", "B") %in% cl), .groups = 'drop') %>%
    pull(n) %>%
    sum
[1] 17
```

Answer (score 2):

A base R approach using `table`, `colSums` and `sum`

```
sum(colSums(table(df) > 0) == 2)
#[1] 17
```